# Always launch new activity instance with no history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there a way to launch an activity as a new instance with no history?

Tried the following in the manifest file.

```
android:launchmode="singleinstance"
android:noHistory=true
```

I am able to achieve what I need, but as soon as the screen is locked the previous activity is displayed. That's what `noHistory` is supposed to do, but not what I need.

Keeping the screen on always would not be preferable as it would drain the battery unnecessarily. Is there any other way to start an activity with a new instance and have no history but also work when the screen is locked?

Answer (score 1):

This will start a activity with new information and no history

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
MainActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: tried the above with android:launchmode=single_instance as well as nohistory but still am not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that  by adding `android:noHistory="true"`

in your android manifest Activity Tag (`ClassName`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this flag in intent.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

The new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished.