# startActivityForResult on calendar event action_insert not returning to app

Tags: android, events, calendar

The following code starts the calendar event editing activity for creating a new calendar event.  Afterwards, I would like it to return to my app via a call to onActivityResult.  That is not happening.  Instead, it is returning to the calendar agenda view activity.

Here's the code that launches the event editor.

```
public void onAddToCalendar (String description)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
  intent.setData (CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
  intent.putExtra (Events.TITLE, description());
  startActivityForResult (intent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_ADD_EVENT);
}
```

What do I need to do to get this to return to my app through onActivityResult?  I'm running android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

just override the following method in the parent activity such as Activity A and B

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Start Activity on your onClick method using

```
   startActivityForResult(intentName, 0);
```

In Child Activity you use/override onStop() method

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
         super.onStop();
     }
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but correct me if I'm wrong here.  The calendar editing activity is not my code - part of the android distribution.  So, I do not have a way that I know of to overide its onStop.  What I'm hoping is that there is a putExtra or some other methodolgy to change its behavior.

Comment: You try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181657/always-launch-new-activity-instance-with-no-history/13182117#13182117

Comment: That's closer.  It returned to the calendar agenda view, but then returned to my app.  Here's the code I'm using now: `    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setData (CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra (Events.TITLE, description);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivityForResult (intent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_ADD_EVENT);  `  So, any ideas on how to get it to immediately return to my app?